# Magento 2 : Error While Flushing Cache

Tags: magento2, error, cache

Whenever I am trying to flush cache, Site is going down and it's giving error 
**Object DOMDocument should be created.**

My Report file is:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:37:"Object DOMDocument should be created.";i:1;s:12580:"#0 public/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/Reader.php(95): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\DomMerger->getDom()
#1 public/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(258): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\Reader->read()
#2 public/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(166): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->prepare('head.calendar')
#3 public/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(144): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->prepareData('head.calendar')
#4 public/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(125): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('head.calendar', NULL, Array)
#5 public/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'head.calendar', Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor))
#6 public/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#7 public/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#8 public/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#9 public/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#10 public/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#11 public/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(244): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#12 public/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(859): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#13 public/vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper/Page.php(171): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('page_content_he...')
#14 public/vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Index/Index.php(43): Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), 'home')
#15 public/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index->execute()
#16 public/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 public/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#18 public/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Cms\\Con...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'customer-app-ac...')
#19 public/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(61): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 public/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Customer\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 public/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Cms\\Con...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'contextPlugin')
#22 public/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/Context.php(106): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 public/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\Context->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 public/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Cms\\Con...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'storeCheck')
#25 public/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/StoreCheck.php(44): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 public/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\StoreCheck->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 public/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Cms\\Con...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'tax-app-action-...')
#28 public/vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(91): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 public/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Tax\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 public/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Cms\\Con...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'weee-app-action...')
#31 public/vendor/magento/module-weee/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(112): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 public/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Weee\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#33 public/var/generation/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#34 public/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 public/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#36 public/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#37 public/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...')
#38 public/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#39 public/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#40 public/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#41 public/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#42 public/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#43 public/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#44 public/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(68): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#45 public/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#46 public/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#47 public/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#48 public/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#49 public/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#50 public/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#51 public/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#52 public/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#53 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

The **exception.log** is empty. Anyone got any idea how to solve?

In **system.log** file I'm getting this

```
main.CRITICAL: Invalid block type:  [] []
```